# Multiple Image Upload Progression problems

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlsession, urlsession, urlsessiontask

I'm trying to upload Several separate images, as long as I upload them 1 at the time it works. But once I try to upload the next image or more than one image the problems starts. 
every image I upload in a series will update all images with the progression of the latest image uploaded. 
When I took more than one images before the upload of the last one was done it will disturb the progression of the others by showing various upload progression numbers randomly.

this is how I update my UI:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "uploadQueueCell", for: indexPath) as! UploadQueueCustomCell

        if cell.progress.text?.lowercased() == "percentage".lowercased()
        {
            cell.progress.text = "0"
        }
            if indexPath.row < uploader.GetUploadQueue().Count()
            {
                let item = uploader.GetUploadQueue().Get(pos: indexPath.row)
                cell.filename.text = item._FileName
                let percentage = String(item._Percentage)
                cell.progress.text = percentage
                cell.cell_image.image = UIImage(data: item._ImageData)
            }
            updateView()
               return cell

    }
    public func updateView() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    }
```

this is how the individual Items in my array is stored :

```
public class UploadQueueCellData
{
    public let _FileName:String
    public let _UploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate
    public let _ImageData:Data
    public let _TaskIdentifier:Int

    public init(fileName:String,imageData:Data,uploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate,taskIdentifier: Int)
    {
        _FileName = fileName
        _ImageData = imageData
        _UploadTaskDelegate = uploadTaskDelegate
        _TaskIdentifier = taskIdentifier
    }
    public var _Percentage:Int
    {
        get
        {
            let test = _UploadTaskDelegate as! UploadDelegate
            let returnval = test._percentage
            return returnval
        }

    }   
}
```

and my delegate for uploading progression

```
    public class UploadDelegate: URLSessionUploadTask, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    public var _response:HTTPURLResponse = HTTPURLResponse()
    public var _error:String? = nil
    public var _percentage:Int = 0
    public var _Filename:String? = nil
    public var _urlSessionTask:URLSessionTask? = nil


    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
    {
        _error = error.debugDescription
    }
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)//->Int
    {
        //Progression
        let progress = Float(totalBytesSent)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        _urlSessionTask = task
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self._percentage = Int(progress * 100)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss how to separate the individual uploads and keep track of their progression everything I do seem to either work towards only being able to track the last upload. or update all of them with the random progression numbers instead of the progression belonging to the individual uploads. is there a way to actually make my model separate the individual uploads and keep track of them separately ? and how would I go about doing that ?

**Edit:**

I think i should add that I send one image at a time but because of connectivity or slow speed could end up with a cached queue of sent items that still is not complete. I'm simply trying to show progression of individual items already send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

My solution was to try and keep track of which file I was receiving the progression on. I know it's probably not the neat solution but it's working atm I did it in this way:

```
 public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64)//->Int
        {
            //Progression
            _Filename =  task.currentRequest?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "filename")
            let progress = Float(totalBytesSent)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
            _urlSessionTask = task
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                self.objQueue?.Get(filename: self._Filename!)._Percentage = Int(progress * 100)
              //  self._percentage = Int(progress * 100)
            }
        }
```

the rest is pretty much the same as before.

with one small exception:

```
public class UploadQueueCellData//:NSObject, UploadURLSessionTaskDelegate
{
    public let _FileName:String
    public let _UploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate
    public let _ImageData:Data
    public let _TaskIdentifier:Int
    public init(fileName:String,imageData:Data,uploadTaskDelegate:URLSessionTaskDelegate,taskIdentifier: Int)
    {
        _FileName = fileName
        _ImageData = imageData
        _UploadTaskDelegate = uploadTaskDelegate
         _TaskIdentifier = taskIdentifier

    }
    private var intPercentage:Int = -1
    public var _Percentage:Int
    {
        get
        {
             return self.intPercentage
        }
        set
        {
            self.intPercentage = newValue

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

your solution lies in **recursion** .just giving to basic idea with example hope you dig into it and create as per required.

for eg. you have **imageArray** with **10 images**

```
        func uploadImageATIndex(index:Int,uploadArray:[UIImage]){
                var position = index

                    self.uploadImageRemote(uploadArray[position]){ dataImage, error -> Void in
                                  //callback when image is uploaded 

                 //check whether position is the last index or not.if not than again call self
                        if !(position == uploadArray.count - 1){
                            position = position+1
                                  //increase the position and again call the self
                            self.uploadImageATIndex(position,uploadArray: uploadArray)
                        }else{
                         //when index becomes equal to the last index return
                            return
                        }
                    }
            }
```

call this method only once by giving **index 0**

```
self.uploadImageATIndex(0,imageArray)
```

Comment: it's a neat example but my problem does not seem related ? I can upload X images but I cannot get the progression of the individual images. this one does not seem to solve that issue ?
I guess I could mention that I do not at any one point send more than one image at a time. but I could come to have a queue of several images depending on network connectivity and speed.